# git - when I checkout I get the bare repo, not my branch

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, jira-agile

I am using bitbucket with a properly set up bare repo established by bitbucket several years ago. A medium-sized team of experienced developers have been using this bitbucket project sucessfully for about 5 years.

Until yesterday, I was having similar success. However, today i recieved a Jira item with a bug to be fixed. As is usual and recommended, I click the Jira item's link to create a branch and then browse to the branch on bitbucket to check it out or clone it.

However, today, I created the branch in Jira and browsed to the branch in bitbucket to check it out (cloning and checkout seem to both put a local copy of the development branch in a local folder for me, maybe one is checked out and the other checks itself out the first time I make a change).

But, today, although a branch is created by Jira, and i can find an active link in Jira that will browse me to the branch in Jira, I cannot locate that branch in the bitbucket list of branches no matter which of all the available methods for finding a branch I try.

And, whether I clone the branch or check it out, sourcetree downloads, not the branch I want (a copy of development with the new branch name to match the task name in Jira) but rather a copy of the bare repository that is the root of the GIT project in bitbucket.

I have tried this repeatedly today in every way I am able. But I am unable to view the new branch in the BitBucket list of branches, and I can only download the bare repository, not the copy of the most recent development branch.

What is going on, or what could have happened?

Comment: it seems that you are mixing jira and bitbucket terms wildly. The jira is not connected to git at all, so 3rd., 4th. and 6th. "jira" should be changed to "bitbucket".

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, Jira is somehow selecting to create the new branch in a different repository from the one I expected. That is why I could not find it in the normal repository.

It is also why when trying to clone or checkout the branch I'm getting the bare repository. This has apparently happened before, about twenty times. There are about twenty branches created in this other repository. All of these have no changes.

That is, they were created under the same error conditions I encountered. Perhaps no one is aware of where the missing branches are being created.

In any case, this is no longer a question, it has become a mystery. So, before the monitor, dings my chips, I'm buggin' out!

Actually, there is one more thing: it's not a mystery. What the problem is, is this: I was not remembering to select the repository in the dropdown in the bitbucket create a branch dialog.

Well ok then!